# Create filters with exp-resso shop

Tags: expresso-store, filter

I want to use exp-resso for building a webshop. At the front-end I want to offer customers filters. The filters should be for color, size, price etc. Does exp-resso have something build in for that or do you need to build it all by your own?

Comment: If you want something like this: http://therunningoutlet.co.uk/products/running-shoes/mens/neutral drop me an email and I'll send you a module I've written (peter@peteralewis.com).

Comment: @peterLewis, send you an email!

Answer (score 4):

Try Reefine: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reefine. It allows you to filter by almost anything and supports the Store custom field.